# Device unique id from C++/CX

Tags: c++, .net, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

Can I get `device unique id(UDID)` from C++/CX code on WP8? Or how can I do it if I doesnt? I've tried already to use `DeviceExtendedProperties`(it doesn't work, probably it is .net only class).

Comment: Have you tried [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724340.aspx) ?

Comment: In phone 8, do you have access to this API?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken) method to get a device-unique ID that is specific to your app.  There are some complications to it, as the value of the ID depends on a number of system factors such as available memory, connected peripherals (think Bluetooth headsets), network connectivity, etc - make sure to read the linked documentation!  A more in-depth discussion of the components of the hardware ID [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431).

The value will be unique to the combination of your app and the specific device, which is more than likely to be enough for app-development purposes.

Note that this API requires a WP 8.1 "Windows Runtime" app, and will not be available to WP8 Silverlight apps.

```
using namespace Windows::System::Profile;

...

IBuffer^ nonce = ...; // optional, see documentation
HardwareToken^ hwid = HardwareIdentification::GetPackageSpecificToken(nonce);

// HardwareToken has a few properties, but the one you're likely interested
// in is HardwareToken.
IBuffer^ id = hwid->Id;
```